# Android app update, assets update

Tags: android, updates

I have an  app and it uses .txt files from *assets* folder. In *assets* folder are more  directories in some depth.
Later I will want to add new files to this assets folder so I'll have a new apk(cause files in assets are part of the apk).
**The question:**  So what happens when someone, who is using my app, wants to update my app(with new files in assets) through *Google Play*, will it uninstall his old version and install the new one or how he receive these new files?
Or **simpler**: What happens during an app update?

Could someone make me keen vision in this a little? Thanks.

Comment: If you add new things in Asset then you must uninstall the older app and install a new one.

Comment: @MD any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old app is just replaced by the new app.

You don't have to worry about that. Apps are always installed completely without loosing data. That is, the .apk file is just replaced. So your assets will be also updated automatically.

Here an example:

Google Play Store downloads the new .apk file.

Next, it replaces the old apk file in `/data/app/` by your new apk file.
That means that all the stuff that is in your new app is now available.

In this way the whole application is replaced.

Comment: So there isn't some way to do a differential install, so that, for instance, if you have 1G in assets and add one more small file of say 1kB you don't have to waste time not to mention add wear cycles to the flash by deleting and re-writing the same 1GB all over again?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. There are definitely way of doing that. Unless you are using OBBs or splitting APKs (which is now supported), the ways of doing it really are outside of the scope of Google Play.