# Can Android replace the contents of the assets folder when an app is updated?

Tags: android, assets

I am developing an app using android studio that delivers information in text files stored in the assets folder. The app works, but if I change the text in the files, I have to uninstall and then reinstall the app to make the changes permanent. However, if I make changes to the app code, the changes take place when the app is updated. I want the assets folder to update in the same way. Is there some way to avoid reinstalling the program to update both code and assets, especially when updating apps to the playstore?

Thanks.

Comment: "The app works, but if I change the text in the files, I have to uninstall and then reinstall the app to make the changes permanent" -- no, you do not. "Is there some way to avoid reinstalling the program to update both code and assets, especially when updating apps to the playstore?" -- this happens automatically. Replacing the app *in situ*, such as via re-running it from your IDE, updates the APK and the assets contained in it. Now, it is possible that Instant Run on Android Studio 2.x has issues here; I have it disabled.

Comment: As CommonsWare says: Are you using Android Studio to run and install your app when you have changed Assets files? If so, then Instant Run may be getting in the way. When downloading and installing from Google Play this will not be a problem as the Assets directory is packed into the .apk that your users will download as a whole so everything is replaced, including the files in the Assets directory.

Comment: [Please check the below question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289028/android-app-update-assets-update)

Comment: @CommonsWare Wait, are you saying that Android Studio is more intelligent about installation so that, for instance, if you add a small asset file to a bunch of large ones it won't delete any of the large ones but leave them as is?

Comment: @Michael: Instant Run tries to do this sort of optimization. I assume that they have done it for assets, though I don't know for certain, as mostly they talked about code and resources. The Play Store also performs binary diffs to try to reduce app update download sizes, and that (hopefully) will skip over unchanged assets. Normal APK installation (non-Instant Run Android Studio, non-Play Store app distribution channels, etc.) will remove and replace everything in the APK, AFAIK.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's good to know, thanks.  Sounds like for development purposes it may be better in some cases to store the assets outside the APK (e.g. in the SD card area or something) until they have stabilized enough.

Comment: @Michael: It might speed up deployments from the IDE somewhat. `adb` speed seems much improved over what it used to be, but there are limits. Having a configurable data source (via dependency injection, `BuildConfig` settings, or whatever) might also be useful in testing.